# AutoTextSize mismatch problem in a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using Android Oreo AutoTextSize capability in my project.
Every thing works fine except that at first when RecyclerView being loaded, some of textView that uses AutoTextSize has a margin bottom on some RecyclerView items but when I scroll down and then come back to that items, problem solves.
and Although in some items, length of TextView is same with another item, but text sizes are different.
You can see my problem in below image :

[When I scroll down and then come back, it is ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2891.jpg)

here is items layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="8dp"
android:background="@android:color/white"
app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
app:cardElevation="3dp">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/fessMetaCL"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:background="@drawable/fees_item_background"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fee_currency_icon"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/fees_update_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@string/lastupdate"
            android:textColor="@color/fees_text_color"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/fee_currency_date"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/fee_currency_stock"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/fee_currency_date"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/fees_text_color"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="@dimen/order_result_text_max_size"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="@dimen/order_result_text_min_size"
            app:autoSizeStepGranularity="@dimen/order_result_text_rise_step_size"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/fees_update_label"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/fees_stock_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@string/stock"
            android:textColor="@color/fees_text_color"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/fee_currency_stock"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/fees_text_color"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="@dimen/order_result_text_max_size"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="@dimen/order_result_text_min_size"
            app:autoSizeStepGranularity="@dimen/order_result_text_rise_step_size"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/fees_stock_label"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/fees_stock_label" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fee_currency_icon"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/others" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/fee_currency_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/fees_text_color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/dashboard_fees_small_font_size"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/fee_currency_icon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/fee_currency_icon" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/fee_currency_price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/fees_text_color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/dashboard_fees_small_font_size"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/fee_currency_icon"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/fee_currency_name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fee_currency_name" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/fee_currency_change"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:textColor="@color/fees_text_color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/dashboard_fees_big_font_size"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/fee_currency_icon"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/fee_currency_icon" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/fees_change_tip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="@string/change"
        android:textColor="@color/fees_text_color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/dashboard_fees_small_font_size"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/fee_currency_change"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/fee_currency_change" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="187dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```